# How can I securely manage and use the API key required for authentication in my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a JavaScript web application that needs to interact with an external API, which requires an API key for authentication. However, I want to ensure that I handle this API key securely to protect sensitive data and prevent unauthorized access.

I initially stored the API key directly in my JavaScript code, but I realized this might not be secure. I expected this approach to work, but I'm concerned about the exposure of the API key.

Comment: Where does that JavaScript code _run_? If it's in your clients' browsers then: no, that's not secure. If you have a backend running JS on a server you control (e.g. with Node.js), then it can be kept secure.